# Logback: Is there a way to conditionally include a grouping token?

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j, janino

I noticed Logback has evaluators. I would like to include an MDC field only if it exists. For instance, lets say I declare this evaluator:

```
  <evaluator name="UID_EVAL">
    <expression>
      if(mdc == null || mdc.get("uid") == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    </expression>
  </evaluator>
```

Then in the pattern I'd like to only include the tag for that if that evaluator is true:

```
<pattern>%eval([uid:%mdc{uid}], UID_EVAL) ...more stuff...</pattern>
```

*note the above code does not work*

So basically, if UID_EVAL comes out true, `[UID:a string from mdc]` will appear, but if false, nothing appears.

Is there a simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to log `uid` only if it exists, or another field if `uid` exists?

Comment: @Kayaman I only want to log the string: `[UID: $uid]` if it exists in the mdc

Comment: Why don't you log the whole MDC then, or are there things you *don't* want to log at the same time?

Comment: Mmm... that's a good point. I don't think there's anything I _don't_ want to log, although I'd prefer to control the formatting.

Comment: That's what I've done. You do want *all* the information in the logs after all, and this way you can add other fields without worrying. The formatting isn't too bad by default, and you could probably modify that too somehow, if nothing else seeing if you can extend `MDC` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluators are for filtering. In your case, you would want to write a [custom converter](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier).